# definition of local field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, local-field

In most books, when defining the local field, the authors require the topology be indiscrete . Why should the topology be indiscrete? If the topology is discrete, can we definie local field?

Comment: I don't think local fields should be equipped with the indiscrete topology. In fact, there is an induced absolute value on a local field, and that defines a non-trivial topology. Maybe you meant to say that the topology is **non-discrete**? Also, of couse you can endow a local field with the discrete topology. But a non-trivial topology can help us understand those fields better.

Comment: You should [look at the correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_field#Induced_absolute_value) between locally compact topology on $(k,+)$ for which the multiplication is continuous, its Haar measure and the absolute value $|x|=\mu(xA)/\mu(A)$ on $k$. The discrete topology corresponds to the trivial absolute value $\forall x\ne 0,|x|=1$.

Comment: @reuns, does there a compact local field? I know the fact  the local field has three types ,but they are not compact.